# Mi script bash no comprueba bien las vars $1 y $2 que le paso al script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

estoy haciendo un script de bash para hacer copias de seguridad de BD. Basicamente quiero algo como : `create_backup.sh {database_name} {table_name}`

y que ejecute `mysqldump database_name.table_name > date.sql` algo asi.

Quiero que `database_name` y `table_name` sea opcional, es decir, si no vienen en vez de esas vars seleccionare todo : `*.*`.

Pero no me lo hace bien, este es mi script:

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$( date '+%F_%H:%M:%S' )

database_name='*'
table_name='*'

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
   $database_name="$1"
fi

if [ -n  "$2" ]; then
   $table_name="$2"
fi

echo "$database_name y $table_name"

echo "mysqldump $database_name.$table_name  > $now.sql"
```

*Aclaracion:* Ahora estoy haciendo haciendo un echo para probar que me salga lo que quiero.

El script no me da error, pero no hace lo que deberia.

Comment: la asignación de variables es `variable="valor"`. En tu caso, estás diciendo `$database_name="$1"`, con `$` inicial, que es incorrecto. Siempre es útil pegar el código en http://shellcheck.net para ver errores generales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitas hacer un `mysqldump` de todas las tablas de una BD no necesitas pasar `*`. Aún así, responderé la duda de como tratar los argumentos.

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$( date '+%F_%H:%M:%S' )

database_name='*'
table_name='*'

# Si no se pasan argumentos:
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No se han pasado argumento, se hará backup por defecto de todas las BBDD y tablas."
fi

# Si se pasa el primer argumento (BD) y el segundo (tabla) se asignan:
if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ]; then
    database_name="$1"
    table_name="$2"
# Sino, si se pasa el primer argumento (DB) pero no se pasa el segundo (la tabla), solo asignamos la BD para dejar la tabla como * 
elif [ -n "$1" ] && ! [ -n "$2" ]; then
    database_name=$1
fi

echo "$database_name y $table_name"
```

Ejemplos:

- Sin pasar argumentos:

```
(base) [01-04-21 00:53] {devops@devops} (~/python)$ -> bash test.sh 
No se han pasado argumento, se hará backup por defecto de todas las BBDD y tablas.
* y *
```

- Pasando solo el primer argumento, es decir, la BD:

```
(base) [01-04-21 00:53] {devops@devops} (~/python)$ -> bash test.sh database
database y *
```

- Si pasas ambos, tanto BD como tabla:

```
(base) [01-04-21 00:53] {devops@devops} (~/python)$ -> bash test.sh database table
database y table
```

---

Nota:

- Dump de una sola tabla de una BD:

```
mysqldump -u <db_username> -h <db_host> -p db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

- Dump una BD:

```
mysqldump -u <db_username> -h <db_host> -p db_name > database.sql
```

- Dump de todas las BBDD:

```
mysqldump -u root -p -h <db_host> --all-databases > alldb.sql
```